# RLC circuit differential equation

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, mathematical-physics

***Question:***

Consider the RLC circuit shown in Figure, with $ = 110 \Omega,  = 1 H,  = 0.001
F$, and a battery supplying $_0 = 90 V$. Initially there is no current in the circuit and no
charge on the capacitor. At time $ = 0$ the switch is closed and left closed for 1 second.
After time $ = 1$ it is opened and left open thereafter.
Find the resulting current in the circuit.
$$(/)+  +(1/) \int_{0}^{t}  (\tau)\tau = e().$$

Needs help in this regard.

*My try:*

$di/dt + 110i+1000 \int_{0}^{t} i (\tau) d\tau=90$

I know how to tackle this. But my question is that how to get rid of integral. Should I replace $i(\tau)$ by $dq/d\tau(=q'(\tau))$ and to apply FFTC.

[image]

Comment: What are your thoughts? No one wants to do your homework/assessment/Exam? for you.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I need to edit it. Then I explain my thoughts.

Comment: Now check sir.  Am I going right?

Comment: You didn't include the figure to show how series/parallel the components  are configured.

Comment: Ok I include the figure.

Comment: Ok sir. This is also a way to get rid of integral but how about initial conditions. I have also problem to set ICs.

Comment: Can anyone tell and help me in making use of ICs in the second line from the initially there is no current in the circuit etc upto left open thereafter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The more usual approach is simply to differentiate the entire equation to:
$$L\,\frac{d^2i}{dt^2}+r\,\frac{di}{dt}+\frac1C\,i=\frac{de(t)}{dt}.$$
You would use the IC's in the course of solving this DE - I would recommend using Laplace Transforms: the IC's get used quite naturally in that process.

Alternatively, if you use the Laplace Transform technique, you can simply transform the integral term as-is.

Comment: Yes, sir you are right. I did that then I got the answer. Thanks.